# Map A Drive To Same Windows Server Using DNS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, mappeddrive

I'm having trouble mapping a drive to a shared folder using a DNS name.

I have 3 windows 2008 Server machines.  All 3 machines have code that needs to be able to access one of the 3 machines.

Machines:

ABC001
ABC002
ABC003

The share they all need to read from is:

```
\\ABC001\FILES
```

All 3 machines can see this location fine, both in code (and via a mapped drive, though that isn't necessary).

However we had a DNS created to point (for now) at ABC001.  Both the DNS and the ABC001 have the same IP when pinged.  The name of the share becomes:

```
\\somedns.example.com\FILES
```

Using this new share name, the code on ABC002 and ABC003 can connect fine to this location.  But ABC001 cannot. I even try to manually map a drive to `\\somedns.example.com\FILES` from ABC001 but it doesn't work -- instead it invites me to enter credentials.  I do this, and it always says wrong password.

I can of course still map a drive to `\\ABC001\FILES` from ABC001, and this works straight away without being asked for any credentials.

Any ideas how to get a windows server to map a drive to itself, via DNS?

Comment: Not confident enough about this to post a full answer, but it sounds like you put a full A record in for this. A CNAME record might do better here. Also, you could try editing the hosts file on `ABC001` to point `somedns.example.com` to `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- unfortunately adding a CNAME isn't possible here.  I tried adding the entry to the 'hosts' file but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: you can try KB 896861 method 2.

Comment: KB 896861 did the trick.  Great - thank you very much.